# Как получить представление какого-то типа данных в компьютере (например, с дополнительным кодом у int)

Tags: c++

Нужно вывести представление структуры в компьютере. Пока получилось что-то вроде этого (оно не работает).

```
template <typename T>
void binary_print(T a) {
    for (char& i = (char&)a; i != (char&)a + sizeof(a); ++i) {
        cout << bitset<8>(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Можно сделать union. Одно поле - это структура или другой тип. Второе поле - массив char, равный по размеру с первым значением.

Comment: `reinterpret_cast<::std::uint8_t const *>(::std::addressof(whatever))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я бы использовал что-то вроде вот этого:

```
template <typename T> void print_bits(const T &obj)
{
    for (auto x : reinterpret_cast<const char (&)[sizeof(T)]>(obj))
        std::cout << ' ' << std::bitset<8>(x);
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Comment: А почему для вызова print_bits(a) (a = 1) выводится 00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000 ?

Comment: little endian -- байт с младшими разрядами имеет младший адрес